# Convert Date to a value compatible with JavaScript to render a timer

Tags: jquery

In my Database, I am saving Date for launch in 2 different fields in below formats:

1st Field for Date: 03/27/2014
2nd Field for Time: 20:30 (am saving in 24 hour format)

Now I am using JQuery Countdown timer http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html to display a timer on my website. The Timer expects value to be passed as Year, Month & date.

The code that renders the Time is :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    /*Put your launch date here: */

    //Year
    var countdown_year = 2014; 

    //Month
    var countdown_month = 3;

    //Day
    var countdown_day = 23;

    //No need to change this line
    var timeTo = new Date(parseInt(countdown_year), parseInt(countdown_month-1), parseInt(countdown_day));


    jQuery(function ($) {
        //var austDay = new Date();
        //austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: timeTo});
        //$('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
    });

</script>
```

I don't know how to convert the date I have in format that is acceptable to the timer script and would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Explain where do you have troubles? You are using the same code as given link.

Comment: ahh sorry to not be clear. I want to convert my dates from 2 fields e.g. "03/27/2014" & "20:30" and convert it into year/month/date time to work with the the above JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   //you need to populate the date below from your database obviously.
    var d = new Date("03/27/2014");
    var countdown_year = d.getFullYear(); 
    var countdown_month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var countdown_day = d.getDate;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/6TQgE/2/

Comment: Ahhh yeah my bad, updated the answer sorry about that couple of typos.

Comment: Thank you Rick for the prompt answer. You saved the day!.